# text searching with whoosh

Tags: python, whoosh

I am tyring to test Whoosh for text searching and right now a simple contrived example is not working for me. I assume I am missing something here. In the following code I would expect it give a single search result but I get 0 hits.

```
import sys
import os

from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT, STORED
from whoosh.index import create_in, open_dir
from whoosh.query import *

#creating the schema
schema = Schema(tax_id=STORED,
                name=TEXT(stored=True))

#creating the index
if not os.path.exists("index"):
    os.mkdir("index")

ix = create_in("index",schema)
ix = open_dir("index")
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(tax_id="17",name=u"Methyliphilus methylitrophus")
writer.add_document(tax_id="17",name=u"Methylophilus methylotrophus Jenkins et al. 1987")
writer.add_document(tax_id="45",name=u"Chondromyces lichenicolus") 
writer.commit()

myquery = And([Term("name",u"Chondromyces")])
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    print searcher.search(myquery)
```

Output:

```
<Top 0 Results for And([Term('name', u'Chondromyces lichenicolus')]) runtime=9.41753387451e-05>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Was able to make it work

```
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
ix=open_dir("index")
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("name", ix.schema).parse(u'Chondromyces')
    results = searcher.search(query)
    for result in results:
        print result
```